# How to modify a substantial amount of data in an existing xml doc in erlang

Tags: xml, erlang, erlang-otp

let's asume you've an existing XML document of about 1 megabyte size. So it's quite small in general but still not trivially small. Now I'd like to work on this document most of the time inserting data like small lists or add text on several nodes inside this document. Let's say about 25 modifications. What's the best way of doing this in erlang.

Thanks.

-dennis

Answer (score 3):

1. Read in the whole document using `xmerl` (comes with Erlang/OTP)
2. Split it up in parts: the ones you don't need to change and the ones you'll modify
3. Let functions manipulate the dynamic parts
4. Put the whole document together again by concatenating the static and dynamic parts
5. Export it to text again using `xmerl`

Comment: Thanks. I'm affraid that this is not so easy if your xml has several levels of nesting. -dennis

Comment: Read up on using the `xmerl` library, and post any follow up questions here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: 1 Meg is small enough to parse all and modify in memory. If the XML structure is complicated its easier to manipulate it that way.  So xmerl is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

xmerl can be disturbing. I have used **[erlsom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlsom/)** library. It is more flexible and converts XML, SOAP Documents, XSL structures direct into erlang records. Download it and follow its documentation.

Xmerl will be stressing. Its documentation is vague. I advise you use erlsom.**[erlsom](http://sourceforge.net/projects/erlsom/)** also ships in with the libraries for creating SOAP clients and servers. its so direct when parsing XML  files or streams into Erlang types